# MySql Workbench frozen, need to retrieve work

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So everyone's worst nightmare just happened to me. I have a final project due tonight at 11:59 for my intro to databases class, and MySQL Workbench crashed on me. I'm on a mac, and it was frozen for about 20 mins. My only choice was to force quit it. I had just copied my entire ERR Diagram, so I quit it thinking I could re-open, and paste. Is there any way to retrieve the work I did? There were about 8 tables and over 100 inserts, and there is no way I can re-do it before it's due. I'm still new to MySQL, so I'm not entirely sure what my options are. Has anyone else experienced something similar? 
If it helps, I did forward engineer the model.
If this isn't allowed, just let me know. I'm desperate and didn't know where else to ask.

Comment: Did you run the code against MySQL? If so, you can do a Mysql dump

Comment: I doubt it, but check this out and see if there's anything in there that might help you.  https://mike42.me/blog/2014-02-01_recovering_auto-saved_files_in_mysql_workbench

Comment: Did you save your query?

Comment: Yeah, but 100 inserts non executed and 8 tables? If the tables had primary keys and foreign keys, workbench would force her to execute the SQL against the MySQL database. Just speculating.

Comment: Sorry about your loss. By the way the work means SQL queries or data in the database. If it is just data then you can report workbench or use another mysql software like phpmyadmin or SQLYog. and if its the queries you may need to rewrite.

Comment: Most of my work was done in an ERR diagram. the only time the script was executed was when I forward engineered it. The inserts were done in the diagram, in the "Inserts" tab. When it was forward engineered, I looked over the script when I forward engineered, and it didn't generate insert statements.
I didn't save anything. I was just on a roll and trying to get it all done. Saving didn't cross my mind. Dumb, I know.
and thank you gview, im reading through the page now.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench keeps the current model open in a temporary folder, which is cleaned up when the model is closed normally. In case of a failure this doesn't happen, so on next start MySQL Workbench recognizes this left-over and marks the model entry on the homepage accordingingly. Just open this model again and MySQL Workbench will recover what it can.